# How to write this LINQ Query in a better way

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, c#-4.0

I have one Linq Query. When I run the query, Only for 10 records its taking 13 seconds to extract the data to the model. I need to know the query which I wrote is good for performance or not. Please guide me what i am doing wrong.

**Code**

```
    var stocktakelist = (from a in Db.Stocktakes
                             select new ExportStock
                                 {
                                     Id = a.Id,
                                     ItemNo = a.ItemNo,
                                     AdminId = (from admin in Db.AdminAccounts where admin.Id == a.Id select admin.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn,
                                     Status = (from items in Db.Items where items.ItemNo == a.ItemNo select items.ItemStatu.Description).FirstOrDefault(),
                                     Title = (from tit in Db.BibContents where tit.BibId == (from bibs in Db.Items where bibs.ItemNo == a.ItemNo select bibs.BibId).FirstOrDefault() && tit.TagNo == "245" && tit.Sfld == "a" select tit.Value).FirstOrDefault()   // This line of Query only makes the performance Issue
                                 }
            ).ToList();
```

Thanks

Comment: I think you need some JOINs. Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb737929) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4115353/106866). Also, make sure the DB.Stocktakes is an IQueryable. I found that IQueryables are way faster than IEnumerables, since IQueryables perform most of the heavy work on the database, instead of retrieving all the data first and then do some tricks with it.

Comment: Only came here to say `tit` :) As jao said, joins are the way to go (if you don't have navigation properties in the objects). Also, make sure you have indexes on `Items.ItemNo` etc. in the database.

Comment: It might help you to first write a SQL query to get the data you want and then transcribe that to a LINQ query. I do this when I'm struggling to write a LINQ query.

Comment: A handy tip might be to try running your code in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) as there is an SQL tab in the results pane which will show you exactly what SQL is generated from your Linq statements. From that you might be able to deduce a better way of writing your epxression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was trying to create the corresponding query with some joins for practice.
I cannot test it and i'm not 100% sure that this query will you get the result
you are hoping for but maybe at least it will give you a hint on how to write 
joins with linq.

```
from a in Db.Stocktakes

join admin in Db.AdminAccounts
  on a.Id equals admin.Id
into adminJoinData
from adminJoinRecord in adminJoinData.DefaultIfEmpty( )

join items in Db.Items
  on a.ItemNo equals items.ItemNo
into itemsJoinData
from itemsJoinRecord in itemsJoinData.DefaultIfEmpty( )

join title in Db.BibContents
   (
       from subQuery in Db.BibContents
       where subQuery.TagNo == "245"
       where subQuery.Sfld == "a"
       select subquery
   )
  on title.BibId equals itemsJoinRecord.BidId
into titleJoinData
from titleJoinRecord in titleJoinData.DefaultIfEmpty( )

select new ExportStock( )
{
    Id = a.Id,
    ItemNo = a.ItemNo,
    AdminId = adminJoinRecord.Name,
    CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn,
    Status = itemsJoinRecord.ImemStatu.Description,
    Title = titleJoinRecord.Value
}
```

Comment: I tried your way of coding. Its working fine. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is so slow is because it is running the 3 inner LINQ statements for **every** item in the outer LINQ statement.
Using LINQ joins will run only 4 queries and then link them together, which is faster.

To find out how to join, there are plenty of resources on the Internet depending on the type of LINQ you are using.

If you're retrieving this data from a SQL server, perhaps consider doing this intensive work in SQL - this is what SQL was designed for and it's much quicker than .NET. **EDIT:** As highlighted below, the work *is* done in SQL if using LINQ to SQL/Entities and using the correct join syntax.

Comment: If OP uses joins correctly, the "intensive work" will be done in SQL.

Comment: Assuming the OP is using LINQ to SQL/Entities (or other?). Using raw LINQ, however, will not automatically get data from SQL.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you should use [Left Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx) in your LINQ just as you would if writing it in SQL.

Your query above will end up looking roughly like this once converted (this is untested, but gives the basic idea):

```
var a = from a in Db.Stocktakes
    join admin in Db.AdminAccounts on admin.Id equals a.Id into tmpAdmin
    from ad in tmpAdmin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join item in Db.Items on item.ItemNo equals a.ItemNo into tmpItem

    from it in tmpItem.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join title in Db.BibContents on bib.BibId equals items.BibId into tmpTitle

    from ti in tmpTitle.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where ti.TagNo == "245" 
        && ti.Sfld == "a"
    select new ExportStock
    {
        Id = a.Id,
        ItemNo = a.ItemNo,
        AdminId = ad == null ? default(int?) : ad.Id,
        CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn,
        Status = it == null ? default(string) : it.ItemStatus.Description,
        Title = ti == null ? default(string) : ti.Value
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Using lambda expressions your query will look like this:

```
        Db.Stocktakes
            .Join(Db.AdminAccounts, a => a.Id, b => b.Id, (a,b) => new { a, AdminId = b.Name })
            .Join(Db.Items, a => a.ItemNo, b => b.ItemNo, (a,b) => new { a, Status = b.ItemStatus.Description, BidId = b.BibId })
            .Join(Db.BibContents, a => a.BibId, b => b.BibId, (a,b) => new { a, Value = b.Value, TagNo = b.TagNo, Sfld = b.Sfld })
            .Where(a => a.TagNo == "245" && a.Sfld == "a")
            .Select(a => 
                new ExportStock { Id = a.Id, 
                                  ItemNo = a.ItemNo,
                                  AdminId = a.AdminId,
                                  CreatedOn = a.CreatedOn,
                                  Status = a.Status,
                                  Title = a.Value
                }
            ).ToList();
```