# Linq Method To Get Data From Another Table Based On ID

Tags: c#, linq

I have a customer table, where I have the basic information *name*, *address*, *postcode* etc. A company can have multiple customers. So the relationship is loosely related to the Company table with the foreign key **CompanyId**. To search for customers I use, a IQueryable method as,

```
private IQueryable<CustomerModel> MapCustomer(IQueryable<Customer> query)
{
    return (from a in query
            select new CustomerModel
            {
                CompanyId = a.CompanyId,
                CustomerId = a.Id,
                CustomerName = a.Name,
                AddressLine1 = a.AddressLine1,
                PhoneNo = a.TelephoneNumber,
                Postcode = a.PostCode,
                ServiceCompletion = a.ServiceCompleteted,
                ServiceDate = a.ServiceDate
            });
}
```

As you can see, if I needed to search all I do is, call the function to return an **IEnumerable**, then use **Where** on it.

```
return MapCustomer(db.Customers.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.Id == id)).FirstOrDefault();
```

The problem is I need to be able to populate the company name instead of the CompanyID. So when I get the result I would be able to see the ***Name*** of the company. What should I do to get this info? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could `inner join` on the `Company` table on the `companyId`, and select the `CompanyName`.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad, I figured I need a `JOIN`, if it were SQL, I wold simply right `SELECT Company.Name, Customer.Name FROM Customer INNER JOIN Company ON Customer.CompanyId = Company.Id`. However Linq, is making me stumble. If I used `from a in query join c in Company on a equals a.CompanyId`, I get **Class name is not valid at this point** and **Cannot resolve symbol CompanyId**. So my question. Anything more?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks, how exactly would I marry **IQueryable** and **Join**?

Comment: @PaulFrancis You were almost there from a in query
join c in Company on a.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115321/linq-to-sql-join

Comment: @PaulFrancis ``a.CompanyId equals c.CompanyId``

Comment: @Ako, I did try that too. It still comes up with **Class name is not valid at this point** on Company and **Cannot resolve symbol CompanyId** on `c.CompanyId`. Company is the Entity/Table.

Comment: @PaulFrancis Try from a in query join c in Company on a.CompanyId equals c.Id

Comment: @Ako, I did that. That is how I still get the error. I think the problem is because I am using it in a Function that has no DBContext to the other table. As `MapCustomer` method, takes in an argument `IQueryable<Cusotmer>` and no where a second argument/ the dbcontext it does not recognize the `Company` table. The only way I figured to do is ignore the function and use the LINQ directly when needed. If you know a way to use IQueryable and another table to JOIN on, that would be great. Cheers !

Comment: If you wish to continue solving this problem, I suggest that extend your question with database schema view where the relation between the tables is shown and a screenshot of the linq-to-sql design view where again you see the class relationships.