# LINQ to SQL .Join syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling with the `.Join` method chaining syntax of `LINQ`.
I need to use this syntax so my query return `IQuerable` results, instead of `IEnumerable`.

I want to join Users with `UserGroups`, and return a new object that includes fields from both tables.
What is the correct syntax for the `JOIN` operation here?

```
var q = dc.Users
    .Join(dc.UserGroups, 
          p => p.UserGroupID, 
          s => s.UserGroupID, 
          x => x.UserGroup) //what is the right syntax?
    .Where(p => p.User.DepartmentID == '123')
    .OrderBy(p => p.User.UserName)
    .Select(p => new UserStruct 
        { 
            UserID = p.UserID,  
            UserName = p.User.UserName,  
            FullName = p.User.FullName,  
            UserGroup = p.UserGroup  
        });
```

Error here is :

> The type arguments for method ....cannot be inferred from the usage.

Comment: is this not a duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115321/linq-to-sql-join

Comment: I haven't seen that post.  Seems pretty close.  Will see what I can do with that solution.  Thanks

Comment: That last parameter is a `Func<TOuter, TInner, TResult>`, but your lambda only has one parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var q = dc.Users
    .Join(dc.UserGroups, 
          p => p.UserGroupID, 
          s => s.UserGroupID, 
          (u, g) => new { User = u, UserGroup = g}) 
    .Where(p => p.User.DepartmentID == '123')
    .OrderBy(p => p.User.UserName)
    .Select(p => new UserStruct 
        { 
            UserID = p.User.UserID,  
            UserName = p.User.UserName,  
            FullName = p.User.FullName,  
            UserGroup = p.UserGroup  
        });
```