# LINQ nested select causes multiple SQL queries

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm attempting to retrieve a list of courses that contains (as a property of each course) a list of departments. The DB schema consists of courses, departments, and a course_departments join table.

My current query (with the unnecessary bits removed) is as follows:

```
ctx.Courses
    .Select(c => new Course
        {
            ID = c.ID,
            Departments = c.CourseDepartments.Select(cd => new Department(cd.Department))
        }
     )
```

This works, but upon inspection in the profiler, it is performing a new query to get each course's departments. How can this query be written to execute it as a single SQL query?

Comment: What is `tc` in this code?

Comment: That's an error entering this in StackOverflow on my part. tc should just be c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you use a nested select the SQL provider translates this to the equivalent SQL (which uses a separate/nested query). You could correct this by using the `Join` method like so;

```
ctx.Courses.Join(ctx.CourseDepartments,
                 c => c.ID, cd => cd.cID,
                 (c, cd) => new {
                     Course = c,
                     dID = cd.dID
                 }).Join(ctx.Departments,
                         c => c.dID,
                         d => d.ID,
                         (c, d) => new {
                               Course = c.Course,
                               Department = d
                 });
```

I have not tested the sample code but that is the basic idea. I pretty much exclusively use method syntax but the query syntax is actually a lot cleaner for joins, you can compare them here [How do I convert multiple inner joins in SQL to LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4115321/linq-to-sql-join) which is what I used to craft my solution.

To summarize the problems cause and solution; if you want one query you have to join from course to coursedepartments to departments, the SQL provider cannot imply that your nested select should be translated to a couple joins. To write the query in LINQ you should use the most similar available SQL constructs, in this case that is a join. There may be other ways to write the query that will inform the query provider of a join implicitly however this is the explicit way of writing the query you want.

Answer (score 0):

I write some code that may fit into your solution. 
Entity definitions are not exactly the same, but that not the case.

```
var query = context.Courses.AsQueryable();
query = query.Include(i => i.CoursesDepartments);
query = query.Include(i => i.CoursesDepartments.Select(cd => cd.Departments));

var newQuery = query.Select(course =>  new 
{
    ID = course.ID,
    Departments = course.CoursesDepartments.Select( cd => cd.Departments),
});

var result = query.ToList();
```

In short overview Include function tells LINQ what related entity should be loaded when fetching Courses entities, otherwise they will be Lazy Loaded.

TIP: I know some people used [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) to learn LINQ, maybe that helps you in the future.